# preg_replace digits and use in results

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How would I use preg_replace to replace:

```
Some text is [[1]] and some is [[2]] bla bla...
```

into this:

```
Some text is 1.____________ and some is 2.____________ bla bla...
```

I have this regex that finds me the right occurrences, but I don't know how to add replacement digits into the result?

```
preg_replace('(\[\[\d\]\])', '_______', $subject);
```

This gets me this result:

```
Some text is ____________ and some is ____________ bla bla...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a capture group and a reference to it :

```
preg_replace('~\[\[(\d)\]\]~', '$1._______', $subject);
```

Comment: Strange is working here http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bLH, but not on my computer. I am only getting ________ ?

Comment: Just for info, that isn't a back_reference but a capture group and it's better to use `$1` than `\1` in the replacement part.

Comment: @Toto Actually yeah in replace functions its not back-reference but we know it by this name! and its a reference to a capture group not a capture group! and about $ why its better?

Comment: @Kasra: because `\1` is a back_reference that can be used **inside** a regex and `$1` is a numbered capture to be used in the replacement part. see: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches

Comment: @Toto Yep, you're right, fixed! thanks for reminding!